How to make a push notification without using Firebase Cloud Messaging and Android Service
I just wondering that Messenger, Discord, X,... doesn't need running background service in order to receive push notification. So is there a way that we can do it too?
I read some post about not using FCM but a service that fetch http constantly, it's not a good idea to do that as it could consume unnecessary data and drain battery.
I have a simple express nodejs server running 24/7. Is using this work?

I think you already have understood the problem, yes it takes a lot of battery keeping a permanent http connection alive. Unfortunately our IP based networks don't proved a better way than using a TCP connection and keeping it alive. Therefore it makes sense to bundle this in one app like Play Services. If you are concerned about data privacy you can send end-to-end encrypted data via FCM.

Thanks. But does FCM have some limitations like request per month, network traffic, etc?

I never had problems until now but I don't develop apps with many users...
